# None type object has no attribute "tosql"

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, mysql-connector

```
df.to_sql('newcmc', con = engine, if_exists='append',index = False)
```

While running the above code it is showing None type object has no attribute "to_sql"

Comment: That means that 'df` is `None`. How did you assign that variable?

Comment: What is `df`?  (I presume a DataFrame, but given it’s a `None` type, something has happened.)  Do `print(df)` and see what you get back.

Comment: df is dataframe                                                                          
df=pd.read_csv("CMC.txt")
df=df.to_excel("newcmc.xlsx",index=None)

Comment: Ah!  `df = df.to_excel…` is messing you up.  It returns `None` and being assigned back to `df`. Remove `df=` from this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all of the comments are (correctly) asserting. The variable `df` is `none`.

And in particular, this comes from `df=df.to_excel("newcmc.xlsx",index=None)` which is giving a `None`.

this would work:

```py
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe that is not None
d = {'a':[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.to_sql('newcmc', con = engine, if_exists='append',index = False)
```